# Check if current date is between date period interval and export the result for each date on separate excel sheet

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr, lubridate

I have a date frame (four variables) with two date columns, start_holiday and end_holiday.I am trying to check if a specific dates within the holiday date range and if it is then export the outcome for that specific date as a one excel sheet.

my input :

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
      ~Code, ~Member_Id, ~Start.Holiday, ~End.Holiday,
  18100532L,         2L,      20190118L,    20190203L,
  18101425L,         1L,      20190118L,    20190203L,
  18101425L,         2L,      20181218L,    20190102L,
  18102843L,         1L,      20181222L,    20190101L,
  18103202L,         1L,      20190202L,    20190303L,
  18103202L,         2L,      20190202L,    20190303L,
  18104148L,         1L,      20181215L,    20181229L,
  18104148L,         2L,      20181215L,    20181229L,
  18105261L,         1L,      20181204L,    20181230L,
  18105261L,         2L,      20190109L,    20190114L,
  18105261L,         3L,      20181205L,    20181222L,
  18107386L,         1L,      20181205L,    20181222L,
  18107429L,         2L,      20181205L,    20181222L,
  18108931L,         1L,      20181217L,    20190110L,
  18109405L,         1L,      20190123L,    20190208L,
  18109405L,         2L,      20190123L,    20190208L,
  18113785L,         1L,      20190118L,    20190122L,
  18114041L,         1L,      20190118L,    20190122L,
  18114329L,         1L,      20181213L,    20181222L,
  18114329L,         2L,      20181213L,    20181222L)
```

I've made it so far which will give me people who were on holiday on Jan 1. However I am looking for a smarter way with less code. Let say I want to check Jan 1 til Jan 11, with this method I have to re-run the script 11 times and export separately for each date. Is there a way we could use to check if some date is within these two intervals, and for each date, export output as a one excel sheet? For example for Jan 1 (only looking at my sample data) 3 people were on holiday and export those as one excel sheet call 0101 , for Jan 2, 2 people were on holiday and export result as one sheet call 0201 , and so on. I hope I was clear enough

## only for Jan 1

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)


df_interval <- df %>%
  janitor::clean_names() %>% 
  mutate(
    Start_H = ymd(start_holiday),
    End_H = ymd(end_holiday), 
    # Create an interval object.
    holiday_Interval = interval(start = Start_H, end = End_H),
    flag = case_when(
      ymd("2019-01-01") %within% holiday_Interval ~ 1,
      TRUE ~ 0)) %>% 
  select(-holiday_Interval)
```

To be more clear, desired output 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you will receive one `.xlsx` file with sheet for each date:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(openxlsx)


df <- 
  df %>%
  mutate_at(3:4, ymd)

dates <-
  seq(
    df$Start.Holiday %>% min(),
    df$End.Holiday %>% max(),
    1
  ) %>%
  as.character()

wb <- createWorkbook()

for (d in dates) {
  temp <-
    df %>%
    filter(Start.Holiday <= ymd(d) & End.Holiday >= ymd(d))
    addWorksheet(wb, sheetName = d)
    writeData(wb, d, temp)
}

saveWorkbook(wb, 'holidays.xlsx')
```